# Trouble updating MKVToolnix apt repo on bionic

Tags: apt, package-management, updates, software-sources, mkv

I used Ubuntu Bionic. I have, among others, the following apt sources configured

```
deb https://mkvtoolnix.download/ubuntu/bionic/ ./
deb-src https://mkvtoolnix.download/ubuntu/bionic/ ./
```

when I `apt-get update`, it fails on this repo, telling me:

```
E: The repository 'https://mkvtoolnix.download/ubuntu/bionic ./ Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

I browsed around, and found a [suggestion](https://superuser.com/a/1331948/122798) to use `apt-get update --allow-insecure-repositories`, but that just changed the error messages I'm getting and didn't resolve the problem.

Help?

Answer (score 2):

It seems the structure of the repository changed at some point. Replace those two lines with the following:

```
deb https://mkvtoolnix.download/ubuntu/ bionic main
deb-src https://mkvtoolnix.download/ubuntu/ bionic main
```

and that should satisfy `apt-get` and let you update.